# For $u \in W^{1, \infty}(\mathbb R^n)$, $|u(x) - u(y)| \le \|\nabla u \|_\infty |x - y|$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $u \in W^{1, \infty}(\mathbb R^n)$, $\varphi \in C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n)$ and
$$\varphi_\varepsilon(x) = \frac{\varphi(x/\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon^n}.$$
We define $u^\varepsilon = \varphi_\varepsilon \star u \in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$. By the mean value theorem, we deduce that
$$|u^\varepsilon(x) - u^\varepsilon(y)| \le \|\nabla u^\varepsilon\|_\infty|x - y|.$$
I have shown, using the fact that $\nabla(\varphi \star u) = \varphi \star \nabla u$ and Holder's inequality, that
$$\|\nabla u^\varepsilon\|_\infty \le \|\nabla u\|_\infty,$$
so that
$$|u^\varepsilon(x) - u^\varepsilon(y)| \le \|\nabla u\|_\infty|x - y|.$$
Now I don't see how I can show that
$$|u(x) - u(y)|\le |u^\varepsilon(x) - u^\varepsilon(y)|.$$
Is it the right way to do that ? Any hint ?

Comment: Except for the end, everything is correct. If you argue that $u_\varepsilon(x) \to u(x)$ for a.e. $x$ (say, on some sequence $\varepsilon \to 0$), then you obtain your claim, at least a.e.

Comment: I didn't know this property, do you have a proof of this ?

Comment: Show that the sequence/family $(u^\epsilon)$ is (locally) uniformly bounded and equicontinuous. Then you can use the Arzela Ascoli theorem to show that $u^\epsilon \to v$ locally uniformly. Since you also know $u^\epsilon \to u$ in $L^1_{loc}$ (I hope you know something like this), you get $u = v$ almost everywhere.

Comment: So actually, there are two facts: 1) Convolutions converge in $L^1$, (2) Convergence in $L^1$ implies convergence a.e. on a subsequence. Are those familiar to you? They should be found in any textbook on Lebesgue integration.

Comment: But the fact that the convolution converges in $L^1$ is true if $u \in L^1$, but here $u \in L^1_{loc}$..

Comment: Here, note that we only need convergence a.e. on any compact subset. Indeed, given $x, y$, we can fin a compact subset $\Omega$ that encloses both $x$ and $y$ in which the inequality holds a.e. Since this inequality holds a.e in $\Omega$, as was previously discussed, you may choose a locally Lipschitz representative so that it holds everywhere in $\Omega$. Note that the constant $ \lVert \nabla u \rVert_\infty $ does not depend on $\Omega$.